# How to transfer a built app to a buyer for private installation on their personal device only?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have built an application in xCode for a client. The client doesn't want to put it in the App Store, just wants to use it personally on his device. How would I transfer the app to him without the client having to do any advanced operations?

Comment: Many ways, refer this doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

Comment: For the testing purpose you can check the link provided by Vasanth, for release/production build you can make `Enterprise Distribution`, for which you can refer this doc [Enterprise Distribution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH33-SW1)

Answer (score 2):

Add their Apple ID to TestFlight and make them a beta tester. Then they can open the rest flight app and download it. Other wise you can just plug their phone into your computer and side load it. or zip up the entire project have them open it on their Mac and side load it from Xcode themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com).you just add the ipa file and provisional profile here and you get the one URL.just send this url to your client,he just open this Url and click download it will automatically download to device. This is easy solution and no need to connect device into your mac also.It is works wireless installation. It is secure also,suppose any one unexpectedly find this url and download into their devices that time it won't download why because in provisional profile we added our client UDID only.Every time it will check UDID if matches to device then only it will install.So it is secure also.